# Selectable=true, but scalable, rotatable=false?

Tags: fabricjs

Can I do that in fabric js? I went through the introduction which only told me how to disable selection. In my particular application i want to the object to be moved to places but not resized or rotated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the documentation: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html
You can use:
- lockRotation
- lockScalingX
- lockScalingY
- lockUniScaling